# Load CheckedTextView items in ListView with checked states set

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

When my activity starts and I initially load my `ListView` with items, I want to be able to set some of those items to checked however that doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using the `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` [layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml) so the items are `CheckedTextView`.

Here's the adapter. Text displays properly however the `Checked` property doesn't seem to be doing anything visually despite it being set to true/false.

```
public class VehicleSubListAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    // ...

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView ?? _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, parent, false);

        var checkedTextView = view.FindViewById<CheckedTextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
        checkedTextView.Text = _items[position].Name;

        // This doesn't seem to do anything
        checkedTextView.Checked = _items[position].Checked;

        // I've even tried this with no change visually
        //checkedTextView.Checked = true;

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here's the activity which can be closed and re-opened but needs to resume from where it left off (some items checked, some items not). That is why things are stored in a global static variable.

If the global list is empty, manually update the lists. Else, load from the global list. It successfully loads from the global list and successfully stores the Checked property of that list as modified in the item click event. However, the checked items aren't shown as checked when the activity loads.

Also I've tried putting the call to `FillList()` in both `OnCreate` and `OnResume` and neither have worked.

```
public class VehicleConditionSubActivity : ListActivity
{
    private List<VehicleConditionItemDTO> _items;
    private VehicleSubListAdapter _vehicleAdapter;
    //...

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.MyAppTheme);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.VehicleConditionItem);

        // Set up action bar
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Set up list view
        ListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
        _items = new List<VehicleConditionItemDTO>();
        _vehicleAdapter = new VehicleSubListAdapter(this, _items);
        ListAdapter = _vehicleAdapter;
        ListView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;

        //...

        // Fill list view
        FillList();
    }

    private void FillList()
    {
        AddFluidItems();
        _vehicleAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void AddFluidItems()
    {
        // I've checked that this is being called correctly
        if (Global.Conditions.FluidLevels.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Global.Conditions.FluidLevels)
            {
                _items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _items.Add(new VehicleConditionItemDTO("1", "Engine oil"));
            // ...

            foreach (var item in _items)
            {
                Global.Conditions.FluidLevels.Add(item);
            }
        }

    }

    // ...

    private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Items already check/uncheck properly when tapped
        // So I just update the global list items checked property
        Global.Conditions.FluidLevels[e.Position].Checked = !Global.Conditions.FluidLevels[e.Position].Checked;
    }
}
```

The layout for the activity is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:minWidth="25px"
  android:minHeight="25px"
  android:background="@color/background">
  <ListView
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@android:id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `.. closed and re-opened but needs to resume from where it left off (some items checked, some items not). That is why things are stored in a global static variable.`. You can store values in a global variable. But you cannot use them at restart of your app as all changes will be gone then. To store a state you need a file or use shared preferences.

Comment: `var checkedTextView = view.FindViewById<CheckedTextView>(Andro...`. FindViewById<> ? var ?

Comment: There's a service running so data persistence isn't an issue for closing and re-opening the activity. As for your confusion over the code, check out the tags. That code is just C# for `CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Selecting Items Programmatically**
>
> Manually setting which items are ‘selected’ is done with the
>   **SetItemChecked** method (it can be called multiple times for multiple
>   selection)

[Customizing A List View's Appearance](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance/)

Note that SetItemChecked is on the ListView.

You can remove the code in GetView that sets Checked.

Then, after (or during the call to FillList) for each item that should be initially checked, call:
ListView.SetItemChecked (position, true);

Comment: You can also override: protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

Comment: and then get rid of:    
   ListView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick; and ListView_ItemClick.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that method used in Java but I wasn't sure the C# equivalent. I thought `ListView.ItemClick` was the way to get it but it's good to know otherwise.